# Drop down List on Click in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

Im working on Excel 2007. Is it possible to create on Click in Drop Down List ?

Example:

I got A2,B2,C2,D2,E2 is Marks for Math,Physic,English,Chemistry,History. And F2 is drop down list contain Type of Student'Attitude included Good,Normal and Bad.

By Default, F2 show Bad, and all the Marks from A2 to E2 keep the same. If I click on F2 to choose Normal, All Marks from A2 to E2 would be add 5% more, the same to choose Good, All Marks would be add 10%.

And I want the Marks change automatically when I click on Bad / Normal / Good.
Is it possible ? Thanks for your concern and help !

Comment: I think you need two columns, one with the inputed grade and one for the calculated ones

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find a sample using an additional column to calculate the results (the forumla has been done only for the 'Good' grade but it is easily expandable)
[image: excel grade sample]